# Elixir Ecto SQL comments /* comment /* Select 1;

Tags: postgresql, mariadb, elixir, ecto

Using Ecto.Query
I'd like to be able to run a query and prepend a comment like this in Postges:

> /* my comment /* 
>   SELECT a.col FROM table a;

I've tried "where: fragment", but it's not working well, and it makes for messy SQL.
Injection in a comment is problematic.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean `*/` instead of `/*` for the closing?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with current Ecto implementation.